# Stream music from android to raspberry pi

Tags: android, bluetooth, gnu, pulseaudio

i am working on a project to send data voice with bluetooth from my phone to raspberry pi. I want to stream this voice from my smartphone and get into my raspberry Pi 3 with pulse audio. And after that i want to get this sound on a audio source with GNU RADIO.

After many research, many tutorials, my raspberry pi do not want to turn as a bluetooth speaker. It impossible to me to use pulseaudio if raspberry pi is not configure as bluetooth speaker.

EDIT: like this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y26aRNU8lMA
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to stream music. It helped me too :
[LINK STREAMING MUSIC PIIII](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=68779)

Try this first link. An code example is also there and packages for installing to run everything.

The second link is more with Bluetooth speakers:
[Music PI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/bluetooth-audio-raspberry-pi-3/)

Comment: thanks for answer. My problem here: I have no bluetooth speaker connected but radio module on my raspberry pi.